# youtube-api 3.0 update video description and/or title

Tags: php, youtube-api

Can someone point me to how I can update a video description using the youtube-api 3.0 version.

I see this code for adding/updating tags

https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/#git/samples/php

but don't know what protocol would be for description and/or title.

Answer (score 4):

Just like that example: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/update_video.php

Instead of adding tags [in these lines](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/update_video.php#L73),

you can set title and desc like:

$videoSnippet['description'] = 'description';
$videoSnippet['title'] = 'title';

That's all.

Comment: That is great.  Thanks.  Do I need to do anything to accept this answer?

Comment: You should have an option to accept. You may have not, cause you don't have enough points. But you can upvote it instead.